# Drupal 7 add shortcode into wysiwyg

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need a possibility to add current year to somewhere on the site in wysiwyg.
Something like 'Now is [YEAR] year'.
I can create module for it, but it's complicated. Is there better idea?
And I have ckEditor installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [token_insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert) to do that.

When you install this module, you can insert the year by this: *date : [Y]*

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/shortcode, and extend it to create your own custom shortcode and use it in ckeditor.

Custom shortcode creation reference link:
http://briannadeleasa.com/blog/drupal-php/shortcodes-drupal-yes-you-can

For example, check out these 3 functions to create our button shortcode:

```
/**
 * Define our process callback function for our [button] shortcode. This
 * takes in our shortcode attributes from the shortcode and if empty, sets the property
 * to the default value stated in this function.  We then pass in our attributes to the
 * theme() function which outputs the HTML.
 *
 * $attrs = shortcode_attrs(array(
 *     'attribute' => 'default_value_goes_here'
 * ),
 */
function custom_shortcodes_shortcode_button($attrs, $text) {
    $attrs = shortcode_attrs(array(
        'link' => 'http://mywebsite.com'
      ),
      $attrs
    );

    return theme('shortcode_button', array('link' => $attrs['link'], 'text' => $text));
}

/**
 * This function uses the attributes passed in to return the HTML of this shortcode.
 */
function theme_shortcode_button($vars) {
  return '<div class="button"><a href="' . $vars['link'] . '">' . $vars['text'] . '</a></div>';
}

/**
 * This function outputs some tips to the user beneath the WYSIWYG editor so they know
 * what the shortcode does and how to use it.
 */
function custom_shortcodes_shortcode_button_tip($format, $long) {
  $output = array();
  $output[] = '<p><strong>' . t('[button link="http://URLhere.com"]text[/button]') . '</strong> ';
  if ($long) {
    $output[] = t('Outputs text that is displayed as a button, which links to a specified URL.') . '</p>';
  }
  else {
    $output[] = t('Outputs text that links to a URL.') . '</p>';
  }

  return implode(' ', $output);
}
```